# How can I select a folder from a variable in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to select a folder, and check that it exists, from user input, this is as far as I got:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd backup
set /p name=Please enter the folder name: 
pause
for /d in ("\%name%\database.txt") do (
echo done
set flag=1
)
if %flag%==0 echo This folder doesnt exist Returning to maintenance menu...
pause
```

Comment: What is your question? You can check the existence of a directory using `IF EXIST "SomePath\DirName\"` _(note the trailing backslash)_.

Answer (score -1):

```
@ECHO OFF
cd backup
set /p name=Please enter the folder name: 
pause
IF EXIST %name% echo "Folder already exists"
IF NOT EXIST %name% echo "Folder does not exist"
echo done
set flag=1
)
if %flag%==0 echo This folder doesnt exist Returning to maintenance menu...
pause
```

or you can make it simple

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p name=C:\:
IF EXIST %name% echo "Folder already exists"
IF NOT EXIST %name% echo "Folder does not exist"
pause
```

Comment: Not only is your code not formatted, both examples fail to follow the correct and specific structure necessary for directory existence.

Comment: Well i re-fix it and it works just fine now. Thanks for pointing that out it was only checking C:\ instead the path that you put in it.

Comment: I did not make mention of `%local_path%` because it wasn't defined and therefore resolved to nothing anyhow. Your fix therefore does not affect anything and my last comment still stands.

Comment: Can you explain? because I have test it many from different path and it works perfect just according to his or her statement: Im trying to select a folder, and check that it exists, from user input, this is as far as I got:

Comment: You could start by formatting the code as I have already mentioned. In it's current format it cannot be used without making guesswork changes as to what you think you've submitted.

Comment: I didn't do no guesswork on it i just made few change on it to make it where you can paste your path to and have it check to see if it exists or not; which from what understand it's what u want; however, I wish u best of luck.

Comment: I don't want anything, _other than for you to improve your answer_, the question is not mine!

Comment: well I just re set it because i don't like how it was taking my code and wrap it together maybe what's what u mean but way it looks now is way i have it in my batch. I don't know if this what u mean; nevertheless, i hope this is what he or she want.